# How can put my python django project on live?

Tags: python, django, server, project, ip-address

I have create a project by python django this project work as an documents Archive by uploding the doucments by the admin panle. The problem is that:
1- I want to deploy on my company server. can anyone tell me how to do it because when I have tried the 'python manage.py runsever ipaddressofservermachine, it is working on server machine but it is not working in other laptops. i thought it should have worked but it did not.
2- I want the uploaded file storage not in my :D drive i wanted to be stored in company server

I have tried many ways and search in youtube i did not find the way to deploy my project live and make it live and accessible for my employes and make the uploaded file storage not in my :D drive i wanted to be stored in company server

Comment:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/